# Meaning of the + V-ing + of

Tags: grammar, gerunds

I have a few questions about the meaning and usage of the expression **the + V-ing + of**.
Here's an example I found in M&W dictionary. In this case, it is used in defining the word "assemble".

> ***the fitting together of*** manufactured parts into a complete machine, structure, or unit of a machine the assembly of an automobile

It appears to me that the gerund here refers to *the process of* assembling manufactured parts into a complete machine. Is my interpretation correct? Also, I'd like to know if it could be used in academic writing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you interpreted correctly, and you can use similar construction in academic writing.  The example you quoted seems to have a missing 'in' after the second 'machine'.